# Limit the options of an input by a previous input in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny app and would like to know how to automatically limit the choices for a select input dependent on the option selected in the first input.
The app looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dslabs)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Traffic Incidents"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            # inputs
            selectizeInput("vehicleInput", "Vehicle",
                           choices = unique(incident$vehicle),  
                           selected="448", multiple =FALSE),
            selectizeInput("groupInput", "Incident Group",
                           choices = unique(incidents$group),  
                           selected="None", multiple =FALSE)
        ),  
        
        mainPanel(
            # outputs
            plotlyOutput("plot"),
            br(), br(),
            plotlyOutput("plot2")
            
        ) 
    ) 
)   

server <- function(input, output) {
    
        d <- reactive({
            filtered <-
                incidents %>%
                filter(vehicle == input$vehicleInput,
                       group %in% input$groupInput)    
            
        }) 
         
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        
        box <- plot_ly(d(), x = ~month, y = ~casualties)  %>%
            layout(title = "Incident Casualties",
                   yaxis = list(title=input$dataInput))
        
    })
    
    output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
        
        box <- plot_ly(d(), x = ~month, y = ~costs)  %>%
            layout(title = "Incident Costs",
                   yaxis = list(title=input$dataInput))
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I would like to know how could I limit the options in the "Incident Group" input by the option selected in the "Vehicle" input, i.e. to be able to choose only incidents groups related to individual vehicles.

I know I should use the observe() function, however, I do have difficulties using it properly.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I think what you need is to update you input "groupinput" and reduce the choices. See more about update input here https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.1/updateSelectInput.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will suffice

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Traffic Incidents"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # inputs
      uiOutput("veh"),
      uiOutput("grp")
    ),  
    
    mainPanel(
      # outputs
      plotlyOutput("plot"),
      br(), br(),
      plotlyOutput("plot2")
      
    ) 
  ) 
)   

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$veh <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("vehicleInput", "Vehicle",
                   choices = unique(incident$vehicle),  
                   selected="448", multiple =FALSE)
  })
  
  d1 <- reactive({
    data <- incidents %>% filter(vehicle %in% req(input$vehicleInput))
  })
  
  output$grp <- renderUI({
    req(d1())
    selectizeInput("groupInput", "Incident Group",
                   choices = unique(d1()$group),  
                   selected="None", multiple =FALSE)
  })
  
  d <- reactive({
    req(d1(),input$groupInput)
    filtered <- d1() %>%  filter(group %in% input$groupInput)
  }) 
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    box <- plot_ly(d(), x = ~month, y = ~casualties)  %>%
      layout(title = "Incident Casualties",
             yaxis = list(title=input$dataInput))
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    
    box <- plot_ly(d(), x = ~month, y = ~costs)  %>%
      layout(title = "Incident Costs",
             yaxis = list(title=input$dataInput))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you YBS, this has worked perfectly! Now I understand how to do this.